# Google Cloud Platform delete or stop instances without prompt

Tags: google-compute-engine

I can use Google compute api to start instances with no problem.
I am actually using a script for some light auto-scaling.
I boot these instances from a snapshot successfully with no block.
However, deleting the instances asks me for confirmation.

```
gcloud compute instances delete ...
```

The following instances will be deleted. Attached disks configured to 
be auto-deleted will be deleted unless they are attached to any other 
instances. Deleting a disk is irreversible and any data on the disk 
will be lost.
 - [xxx-client-1] in [us-central1-f]
 - [xxx-client-2] in [us-central1-f]
 - [xxx-client-3] in [us-central1-f]

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y

I want to delete without prompt.

---

I would be ok with stopping the instances, but this seems to fail:

```
gcloud compute instances stop ...
```

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances) Invalid choice: 'stop'. Did you mean 'list'?

Has 'stop' been changed?

Comment: Have you tried using managed instance groups? https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/ They have a target size and resize operation to automate most of what you are doing here manually....

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Specify `--quiet` or `-q` on your delete command. This will disable prompts (and assume defaults). `gcloud help` describes this and other gcloud flag options available on all commands.

Regarding 'stop', what version of gcloud are you using (you can run `gcloud --version` to find out)? Sounds like your gcloud client is old.

Comment: For anyone wondering, at least for secrets, you still see messages like "Delete secret foo."